# How to change folder icons (eg. the source folder) in common navigator view in an eclipse-rcp application?

Tags: java, icons, eclipse-rcp, navigator, cnf

As you can see in the title of this post I have a question concerning folder icons in a common navigator view used by an eclipse-rcp application.

Is it basically possible to change the icon of a standard folder in the navigator view? My goal is to change the icon of the source folder of a created project. It is important to mention that there is an own created project nature.

So every created project with that specific nature should have a custom icon for the source folder, but actually I have no idea where I am able to modify that icon.

So the question is: Which part of the rcp-application is responsible to handle these icons? Since there is a specific project nature, I would say that the nature should add these customizations, right?

[image: Folder icon I would like to change]

Here you can see the default folder structure. I would like to change the icon of the src folder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

---

Solution:

For more information, [please visit this link.](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Decorators/decorators.html)

(1) Add the extension point:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.decorators">
<decorator
    id="at.fhjoanneum.segof.wsmleditor.natures.decorators.SourceFolderDecorator"
    label="Source Folder Decorator"
    state="true"
    class= "at.fhjoanneum.segof.wsmleditor.natures.decorators.SourceFolderDecorator"
  objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder"
    adaptable="true">
    <description>
      Source Folder Decorator
    </description>
  </decorator>
</extension>
```

(2) Create the decorator class:

```
    public class SourceFolderDecorator extends LabelProvider implements ILabelDecorator {

        public SourceFolderDecorator() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public Image decorateImage(Image image, Object element) {
//return the image
            return null;
        }
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change the image of any object in the navigator, you can use a label decorator. Check the `org.eclipse.ui.decorators` extension point.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The org.eclipse.ui.decorators extension point did the trick for me!